# To what extent is the space captured by functionals on it

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to work in the most general settings. Let us say we have a normed space $\mathcal{B}$. To what extent can we capture properties on the space by studying the functionals on this space?

Comment: It's only vaguely related to what you have in mind, but the question reminds me of the standard result that for any compact manifold $X$, the maximal ideals of $C(X)$ are of the form $\mathfrak{m}_x = \{f\in C(X):\, f(x) = 0\}$ for $x\in X$.

Comment: Interesting and ambitious question... Why especialy simple normed spaces ? Banach spaces are much richer. On the other side, Schwartz space (of distributions) is  based on semi-norms...

Comment: For sure I would love to understand that as well !

Comment: There's plenty of nonisomorphic spaces with isomorphic duals so probably not very much. You can say something, for example if the dual is separable so is the starting space, but you can't even tell if $\mathcal B$ is complete by looking at the dual, so there's probably very little to be said

Comment: @JeanMarie I would like to know more on Schwartz space (of distributions).

Comment: I advise you to begin gently by the historical context, such as in this article (http://sites.mathdoc.fr/OCLS/pdf/OCLS_1982__63__11_0.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know if functionals are dense in certain space then we can capture a lot of information about the original space given this fact? I have my reason to believe some theorem like that might exist.